# download image file from given google chart api url using php

Tags: php

i want to download image returned by this url using a link like `<a href="">Download</a>` and on click of this link download box should appear so user can save image to his/her system. here is the url that return image

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chld=L|0&chl=http%253A%252F%252Fnetcane.com%252Fprojects%252Fyourl%252F3
```

i don't want to save the image to server is it possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Original Question

You can stream or proxy the file to your users by setting up a simple PHP download script on your server. When user hits the `download.php` script below it will set the correct headers so that their browsers asks them to save a download. It will then stream the chart image from google to the users browser.

In your HTML:

```
<a href="download.php">Download</a>
```

In download.php:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="chart.png"');
$image = file_get_contents('http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chld=L|0&chl=http%253A%252F%252Fnetcane.com%252Fprojects%252Fyourl%252F3');
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($image));
echo $image;
```

### Passing in dynamically generated chart API URLs

In your HTML:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?my-generated-chart-api-url';
<a href="download.php?url=<?php echo urlencode($url); ?>">Download</a>
```

In download.php:

```
$url = '';
if(array_key_exists('url', $_GET)
   and filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
     $url = $_GET['url'];
}
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="chart.png"');
$image = file_get_contents($url);
header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($image));
echo $image;
```

Comment: Unlikely that the OP is in control of Google Charts server.

Comment: @Piskvor control is not required. This is all hosted on the OPs hosting and merely stream the contents of googles output to the user.

Comment: aha, now I get your point. +1 (although the matter of ToS still applies - I'm pretty sure this is explicitly forbidden with GMaps, not sure about GCharts)

Comment: great!!! :) it works for static url thank you so much...i don't know why i'm not getting full url when i send ur in querysting it only return chs paramater can you help me in this why its not returning full url? download.php?url=generated-api-url

Comment: I think you might need to use `urlencode()` on the `generated-api-url` parameter in your URL (`download.php?url=generated-api-url`). See http://php.net/urlencode

Answer (score 0):

No, not really. Since the image is generated at `chart.apis.google.com`, and you don't have control over that server, you can't make it send the `Content-Disposition` header with that image; therefore, browsers will display that image.

What you technically *could* do (but I'm not sure if Google's ToS allows it, better check), is to link to your server, which will proxy the download and add the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will not be able to do that.
The closest thing would be to dynamically get the image data using PHP and then serving it with the header **Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=qr.png**

```
<?php

$img_data = file_get_contents("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chld=L|0&chl=http%253A%252F%252Fnetcane.com%252Fprojects%252Fyourl%252F3");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
header("Content-Length: " . strlen($img_data));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=qr.png");
print $img_data;

?>
```

Code is untested, but I think you get the gist of it.
Hope its what you're looking for.

Comment: It produces a PNG and not a JPG. So it should be `Content-Type: image/png`.

Comment: Indeed, there was a warning about that below my code. Fixed now thanks.